# concatenate words in netlogo

Tags: foreach, concatenation, netlogo

NetLogo users

I want to make a list which concatenates lists, for example

Here is list 1    : [ 0 1 4 6 8]

and here is list2 : (word "turtle")

then I'd like to make list which ["turtle 0" "turtle 1" "turtle 4" turtle 8"]

How could I possibily make this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that (word "turtle") is just "turtle", so I'm not quite sure what you want.  But this should cover it.

```
to-report append-word [w xs]
  report map [[x] -> (word w " " x)] xs
end

to-report append-words [ws xs]
  report map [[w] -> append-word w xs] ws
end

to test
  let ws ["turtle" "rabbit"]
  let xs [0 1 4 8]
  print append-word item 0 ws xs
  print append-words ws xs
end
```