# Making agentset outof list

Tags: list, foreach, netlogo, agentset

This is relevant to the previous question just asked.

How can I convert list(which representing turtles) to a agentset?

For example, I want to make

agentset which contains 4 elements [turtle 0 turtle 3 turtle 4 turtle 7]

out of list ["turtle 0" "turtle 3" "turtle 4" "turtle 7"]

I've tried "foreach" before.

Thank you in advance~!!

Comment: The user's previous question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889591/concatenate-words-in-netlogo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why you would need to work with a list like

```
["turtle 0" "turtle 3" "turtle 4" "turtle 7"]
```

in the first place. Storing references to agents as anything other than direct references to the agents is usually not a good idea.

That being said, you can convert such a string to an agentset with:

```
turtle-set map runresult ["turtle 0" "turtle 3" "turtle 4" "turtle 7"]
```

If any of those turtles don't exist, they will just be excluded from the resulting agentset.

Still, the whole thing strikes me as somewhat ill advised. If you tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish, maybe we could suggest a better approach altogether.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Nicolas : I was trying to elicit some subset of agents by certain numbers. And those numbers are added as loop goes on : like first [turtle 0] then [turtle 0 turtle 3], [turtle 0 turtle 3 turtle 4] and so on. The method you suggested results 0 agents, not 4. However I feel like "runresult"could make some answers. Thank you again~!!

Comment: As a general rule, try to avoid using agent numbers. This is a roundabout way of doing things that has zero advantages and often lead to subtle bugs. Like Luke C says: just build your list to contain agents in the first place.

Comment: Ah-ha~! Then I'll probably re-do the whole code. Thank you Nicolas for your great help~!!:)

Comment: Could it be ways that can subtract agents from agentset sequentially as loops goes by?

Answer (score 0):

Are you constrained for some reason to working with a list of strings? If not, but you still want a list, I'd recommend just building your lists to contain agents in the first place. If you're writing this to a file later, it will be converted to string anyway. Internally it's much easier to work with the agents directly.

To make a list of agents based on a list of numbers:

```
globals [ turtle-list num-list]

to setup 
  ca
  reset-ticks

  crt 3   

  set num-list [ 0 1 2 ]
  set turtle-list map [ i -> turtle i ] num-list 
  print turtle-list      
end
```

Note that if the list contains a `who` number for a non-existent turtle, you will get a `nobody` in your list.

**Nevermind all this, just do what @NicolasPayette says.**

<del>Then you *can* use `foreach` to easily build your agentset for your `turtle-list`:

      foreach turtle-list [
        t ->
        set turtle-agentset (turtle-set turtle-agentset t )
      ]

However, if your end goal is an agentset and you don't need a list, you can skip a step and just build the agentset directly:


    to setup 
      ca
      reset-ticks

      crt 3   

      set num-list [ 0 1 2 ]

      set turtle-agentset nobody 
      foreach num-list [
        n ->
        set turtle-agentset (turtle-set turtle-agentset turtle n )
      ]
      print turtle-agentset      
    end</del>

Comment: I would strongly advise against constructing an agentset incrementally like you are doing in the last part of your answer. Adding to an agentset is expensive: NetLogo needs to rebuild the whole agentset each time you add one agent. Adding to lists, however, is very cheap, so if you really have to build an agentset one agent at a time, it's faster to build a list _and then_ convert it to agentset with `turtle-set my-list`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @NicolasPayette, I didn't know you could do `turtle-set my-list`.

Comment: The first part of your comment("I'd recommend just building your lists to contain agents in the first place.") is completely right. All of the problem coming from not able to make list which contains valid turtles. Even turtle-set is not helpful that much. Is there anyway I can make right form of agentset from similar strings? : making [ [agent 0 agent 1 ] from ["agent0" "agent1"]