# NetLogo :Loop with changing agents

Tags: loops, netlogo

In the last 24 hours I have posted 2 questions and fortunately got all of them answered.

However, problem still exists.

Here is what I am planning.

I like to make a miniature market model where agents are looking for their nearest neighbors and transact.

If the distance is quite close(less than 1 patches) then barter starts.

There is one condition that I like to impose,

that is, when the transaction is finished, each agent is looking for the other agents for another transaction, even if current agent is situated closest.

As commented, I like to make a agentsets continually updating according to their newset transaction partner.

I've tried to make list of strings(representing transaction partner) but fail to convert them again into valid agentsets.

How can I solve this problem?

If you have any good ideas other than boundary of my questions please comment.

Thank you for all.

(I'm surprised at the immediate answers, that's thankful too
 Here is the code I'd tried...)

```
to setup
clear-all
reset-ticks
ask patches [ set pcolor white ]
create-turtles num-turtles [
setxy random-xcor random-ycor
set energy random-gamma 10 0.5
set trust random-float init-trust
]
ask turtles [
    set color scale-color green energy 0 99
    set shape "default"
  ]
end


to go
  ask turtles [
    while [any? other turtles-here] [fd 1]

;    let the-other-turtles [who] of other turtles
;    let the-other-closest-turtles remove my-former the-other-turtles
;    let ws ["turtle"]
;    let other-closest-turtles append-word ws the-other-closest-turtles
;    let ls other-closest-turtles
;    let id the-other-closest-turtles
;    set other-closest-turtles create-other-turtles ws ls id
;    let closest-turtle other-closest-turtles with-min [distance myself]

    let closest-turtle other turtles with-min [distance myself]
    set closest-turtle one-of closest-turtle
    while [closest-turtle = nobody] [fd 1]
    if closest-turtle != nobody [face closest-turtle fd 1]
    if distance closest-turtle <= 1 [transact]
    if energy + trust <= 0 [die]
    ]
  tick
end

to transact
  let stronger max-n-of 2 turtles [trust]
  let weaker min-n-of 2 turtles [trust]
  ask stronger [
    set energy energy - 1
    set trust trust + 1.5
    set my-former weaker
  ]
   ask weaker [
    set energy energy + 1.5
    set trust trust - 1
    set my-former stronger
  ]
end
```

Comment: What is it that you can't do? The question asks about constructing an agentset from a string. We would need to see an example string input and expected output to be able to help with that problem. But such a solution would be taking you further down the wrong path. You seem to be constructing a string with who numbers in it. It is almost certainly better to be simply constructing an agentset in the first place and use the `turtle-set` primitive to add the new turtles. This is what http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896539/making-agentset-outof-list/43898915#43898915 is also saying

Comment: Yes,  @JenB.  You are right, it's far better to collect agentset in the first place rather than constructing list indicating turtle's name. However, I was able to make list composed of strings which is look like ["turtle 0", "turtle 2", ..."turtle 15"] by concatenating words and numbers. However, it wasn't possible to enlive agentset from those strings. Thanks for comment anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a list of strings, you can have a list of agents so there is no need to convert between strings that describe turtles and the turtles themselves. Agents can be appended or removed with the list manipulation.

Here's a complete example that works with lists of agents to create an agentset.

```
to testme
  create-turtles 5
  let mylist (list turtle 1 turtle 3 turtle 4)
  let myset turtle-set mylist
  show myset
end
```

But Nicolas's answer to your previous question show how to convert strings.